# How do I get the most recent entry by condition in EF Core?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core

I have a table with the following structure (and sample data):

| Identifier | UseDate | PartId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a123 | 05/01/2000 | 237 |
| a123 | 05/01/2000 | 4656 |
| a123 | 01/01/2000 | 2134 |
| a124 | 04/01/2000 | 5234 |
| a124 | 01/01/2000 | 2890 |

I need to get the most recent entry of every (non-unique) identifier, but at most one per identifier.

The SQL-Query (MariaDB) that seems to fulfill my problem is the following:

```
SELECT a.Identifier, a.MaxDate, b.PartId, b.UseDate 
FROM
(SELECT Identifier, MAX(UseDate) AS MaxDate FROM MyTable GROUP BY Identifier) a
LEFT JOIN MyTable b ON a.Identifier = b.Identifier
WHERE a.MaxDate = b.UseDate GROUP BY a.Identifier;
```

However I need this to work with C# and EF Core (Pomelo.EntitiFrameworkCore.MySql 5.0.3), my attempts have been:

```
var q1 = db.MyTable
            .GroupBy(t => t.Identifier)
            .Select(t => new { Identifier = t.Key, MaxDate = t.Max(x => x.UseDate) });

return new ObjectResult(db.MyTable
    .Join(
        q1,
        t1 => t1.Identifier,
        t2 => t2.Identifier,
        (t1, t2) => new { Identifier = t2.Identifier, PartId = t1.PartId, MaxDate = t1.MaxDate, UseDate = t1.UseDate })
    .Where(t => t.UseDate == q1.First(x => x.Identifier == t.Identifier).MaxDate)
    .GroupBy(t => t.Identifier)
    .ToList()
);
```

and

```
return new ObjectResult(db.MyTable
    .GroupBy(t => t.Identifier)
    .Select(t => t.OrderByDescending(x => x.UseDate).FirstOrDefault())
    .ToList()
);
```

The first one throws this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: "Unable to translate the given 'GroupBy' pattern. Call 'AsEnumerable' before 'GroupBy' to evaluate it client-side."

The second one essentially yields the same, just complaining about the LINQ expression instead of the GroupBy.

I want to avoid using raw SQL, but how do I correctly (and hopefully efficiently) implement this?

Comment: What EFC version are you targeting?

Comment: I'm using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 5.0.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to write such query in LINQ, with most of them being able to be translated by EF Core 5/6+.

The straightforward approach once you have defined a subquery for the necessary grouping and aggregates is to join it to the data table, but not with `join` operator - instead, use row limiting correlated subquery (`SelectMany` with `Where` and `Take`), e.g.

```cs
var query = db.MyTable
    .GroupBy(t => t.Identifier)
    .Select(t => new { Identifier = t.Key, MaxDate = t.Max(x => x.UseDate) })
    .SelectMany(g => db.MyTable
        .Where(t => t.Identifier == g.Identifier && t.UseDate == g.MaxDate)
        .Take(1));
```

If the ordering field is unique per each other key value (i.e. in your case if `UseDate` is unique per each unique `Identifier` value), you can use directly `Join` operator (since lo limiting is needed), e.g.

```cs
var query = db.MyTable
    .GroupBy(t => t.Identifier)
    .Select(t => new { Identifier = t.Key, MaxDate = t.Max(x => x.UseDate) });
    .Join(db.MyTable,
        g => new { g.Identifier, UseDate = g.MaxDate },
        t => new { t.Identifier, t.UseDate },
        (g, t) => t);
```

or directly apply `Max` based `Where` condition to the data table:

```cs
var query = db.MyTable
    .Where(t => t.UseDate == db.MyTable
        .Where(t2 => t2.Identifier == t.Identifier)
        .Max(t2 => t2.UseDate)
    );
```

Finally, the "standard" LINQ way of getting top 1 item per group.

For EF Core 6.0+:

```cs
var query = db.MyTable
    .GroupBy(t => t.Identifier)
    .Select(g => g
        .OrderByDescending(t => t.UseDate)
        .First());
```

For EF Core 5.0 the grouping result set inside the query must be emulated:

```cs
var query = db.MyTable
    .GroupBy(t => t.Identifier)
    .Select(g => db.MyTable
        .Where(t => t.Identifier == g.Key)
        .OrderByDescending(t => t.UseDate)
        .First());
```